Как лучше подключаться к команде со стороны XAML?
Обычно я делаю привязку вот так вот - Command="{Binding SomeCommand}", где SomeCommand это команда из DataContext.
Но вот в этом учебном проекте https://github.com/xellans/LearnMvvm.git я столкнулся с необычным для меня вариантом
<RadioButton Command="{local:SetCurrentContext}" CommandParameter="PersonVM" Content="{DynamicResource Lang1}"></RadioButton>

Приемлемый ли это способ привязки к командам? И какой способ считается более правильным?

Я считаю этот способ плохим, ибо так у вас вечно в памяти висят статичные объекты команд. Для единичного "локатора" может быть и да, но не для всего приложения. И кстати, если откроете к примеру AuthUserControl.xaml, то увидите там обычные привязки. А вот использовать локатор или нет, это уже решать вам. Я лично не вижу в нем смысла, только нагружает код... Хотя в больших приложениях смысл может и есть.

Для того, чтобы данная привязка работала, ваша команда (и любой другой объект для привязки) должна быть статичная, открываем код, смотрим, и действительно:
public static readonly RoutedUICommand SetCurrentContext = new RoutedUICommand(
    "Задание текущего контекста навигатору, находящемуся в ресурсах, вызвашего команду, элемента.",
    "SetCurrentContext",
    typeof(NavigatorLocator));

Ну а статика зло, ибо как минимум

Статика плохо тестируется
Статика вечно висит в памяти даже тогда, когда нам этот объект вовсе не нужен
Ну и др., тонкости, которые надо учитывать

Я не говорю, что у вас не должно быть статики, я говорю, что лучше обходиться без нее, если есть такая возможность, а в этом конкретном случае, такая возможность есть.
А теперь подумайте, как вы будете реализовать другие свои команды для привязки вида {local:SetCurrentContext}? Плодить тонну статичных объектов? Думаю
и сами понимаете, что это глупое решение.
Так что, для единичного использования, как в примере, локатора (о нем поговорим чуть позже), такой подход может и имеет смысл, но делать все свойства для привязки статичными, это стрелять себе в ногу. Если более детальней изучить код из примера, то увидите там дальше нормальные команды и нормальные привязки, например, AuthUserControl.xaml, в нем есть Command="{Binding AuthorizeCommand}", а в VM уже стандартное, не статичное свойство public RelayCommand AuthorizeCommand { get; }.
Теперь что касается локатора
Скажу честно, мне данный подход не нравиться по нескольким причинам:

Статика - как и писал выше, я против нее, а локаторы зачастую на ней основаны.
Локаторы часто внедряются в ресурсы (View слой), и именно XAML им руководит (создает, хранит, управляет сроком жизни, и т.д.), а это значит, что мы теряем полный контроль над ним, что очень плохо. Также подобное плодит такие костыли, как в показанном примере (файл App.xaml.cs -> (NavigatorLocator)this.FindResource("locator");).
Код сильно усложняется ради того, что можно сделать куда проще.

Локатор хорош тогда, когда у вас очень большой проект, и то не факт, ибо как и в указанном примере, в проекте используется IoC контейнер, через который мы без труда можем запросить все то, что нам надо. Так что, я лично не стал бы использовать вот так локатор, но решать вам, стоит оно того, или нет.
А теперь покажу почему я считаю "локатор" избыточным
Возьмем за основу то, что у нас проект будет использовать IoC контейнер (в предложенном примере, это InstancesProvider, в моем случае это будет библиотека Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

Создаем новый проект

Открываем App.xaml и убираем StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"

Создаем класс для нашего окна, пусть будет стандартное MainViewModel

Открываем App.xaml.cs и переопределяем там OnStartup, прописывая в нем инициализацию контейнера, получение из него окна и VM, ну и открытие окна, получаем что-то такое:
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddTransient<MainViewModel>()
        .AddTransient<MainWindow>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var window = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
    var viewModel = serviceProvider.GetService<MainViewModel>();

    window!.DataContext = viewModel;
    window!.Show();
}

Это "топорная" реализация, по хорошему за "маппинг" должен отвечать отдельный сервис, который тут мы просим и через него открываем, но для примера (да и не только), думаю сойдет.

Запустим проект и увидим пустое окно. Поздравляю, мы сделали проект с IoC контейнером.


Теперь давайте подумаем про контент (страницы), пусть за них отвечает отдельный сервис, который будет оповещать слушателей о том, что страница изменилась.

Создаем интерфейс, который будет являться "контактом" для VM слоев страниц, пусть это будет простой и пустой interface IPage.

Теперь создадим еще один интерфейс, который будет описывать уже сам сервис, точней то, что "публичное", а именно метод изменения контента, да и событие, что-то такое:
public interface IContentService
{
    event Action<IPage>? OnPageChanged;
    void Change<TPage>() where TPage : IPage;
}


Теперь реализуем сам сервис, максимально просто, что-то по типу этого:
public class ContentService (IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : IContentService
{
    public event Action<IPage>? OnPageChanged;

    public void Change<TPage>() where TPage : IPage
    {
        var page = serviceProvider.GetService<TPage>();
        if (page is null) return;
        OnPageChanged?.Invoke(page);
    }
}


Регистрируем сервис в контейнер .AddSingleton<IContentService, ContentService>()

Теперь реализуем MainViewModel
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel(IContentService contentService) 
        => contentService.OnPageChanged += page => CurrentPage = page;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private IPage? _currentPage;
}

На ObservableObject и ObservableProperty внимание не обращайте, у вас тут может быть любая реализация INotifyPropertyChanged. В мое случае используется CommunityToolkit.MVVM.

В XAML окна пропишем <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />, для примера этого достаточно.


И вот уже я думаю видно, какой простой у нас код, мы без каких либо ресурсов, статических объектов, создали сервис, внедрили его, и теперь где угодно можем использовать. А теперь взгляните на тот локатор и ответьте на вопрос "а зачем?"... Я вот лично на него ответить так и не смог)
Дальше пример я думаю смысла писать нету (если нужен, говорите, дополню), но в целом, просто создаем VM под нужные страницы и наследуем их от IPage и регистрируете каждую в контейнере, а также внедряем в нужную VM (да и не только) IContentService если нам требуется смена страницы, ну и вызываем метод Change() с нужным типом VM страницы для открытия (contentService.Change<LoginVM>();).
Собственно, это мои мысли на этот счет, думаю объяснил доходчиво почему мне не нравиться такие привязки, и почему я не очень люблю локаторы, особенно, имея под руками IoC контейнер...

В класс ContentService передаётся IServiceProvider, который является локатором.

@AlexanderPetrov В ответе идет разбор конкретного класса, конкретной реализации "локатора" (поэтому я это название в кавычки и беру), а не паттерна в целом. Так-то реализовать можно что угодно и как угодно)

@EvgeniyZ ясно. Спасибо вам огромное.
